# Merge tags less and lesscss

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

Can the tag [less](/questions/tagged/less) and [lesscss](/questions/tagged/lesscss) be merged? When I look at the description it is the same thing.

**Update**

What about retagging [less](/questions/tagged/less) to [lesscss](/questions/tagged/lesscss). And change to tag info of [less](/questions/tagged/less) to represent the *nix `less` command. Since the commenters rightfully pointed me to this. The only thing that might be an issue is people don't reading the tag info and wrongfully adding [less](/questions/tagged/less) to their [lesscss](/questions/tagged/lesscss) question.

What do you guys say about this? Is this possible or will the `less` followers suddenly be following the *nix less?

Comment: And what should we tag items about the Unix `less` utility?

Comment: I'd considered this for a long time, but it's what @Kevin mentioned that makes me very hesitant on doing anything about it.

Comment: @Kevin I'm currenlt on page 4 of the pages tagged [tag:less] on it's only lesscss I see.

Comment: @PeeHaa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less+bash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less+unix

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn can you please look at my update question?

Comment: That sounds great, but yeah, tag followers will be a problem here... as for adding tags to new questions, after retagging, [lesscss] will have far more questions than [less], and will show up first in the list of suggested tags. That should make it easier for most people. Hmmm...

Comment: There's currently a discussion over on MSO regarding these tags, with regard to the unix utility - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283550/1080648