# Should "obvious synonyms" be flagged, or should I just wait to gain tag rep and then vote to make them synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Take [less](/questions/tagged/less) and [less-css](/questions/tagged/less-css) for example — the two tags should **obviously** be synonyms. I don't have enough rep on those tags to nominate either as a synonym of the other, or even vote on it.

Should such obvious cases be flagged, or perhaps posted as feature requests on Meta... or should I just patiently wait until I have enough "tag rep"?

Comment: Note that a handful of questions in that tag are about [the pager `less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less), not the CSS thing.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119806/merge-tags-less-and-lesscss

Comment: The rep requirements related to tags are ridiculous.  Perhaps on the trilogy sites there are enough high-rep users, but nowhere else.  It just won't get done unless you bring it to Meta.

Comment: Bringing it to Meta isn't such a bad idea anyway, as there are often alternative uses for tags you hadn't considered. The community can help come up with a better solution.